# Will Windows 10 automatically re-install an uninstalled update?

Tags: windows-10

A recent Windows 10 update (KB5000802 and KB5000808) is causing BSOD when trying to print. The printer manufacturer is advising us to uninstall the update. What happens then? Will Windows re-install that update again? If Microsoft fixes the update, will the fixed update get installed?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-temporarily-prevent-a-driver-update-from-reinstalling-in-windows-10-17df0ef3-7480-36e9-0ed9-118351398897

Comment: kb5001330 just came out today, lets hope it fixes the BSODS for printers especially impacting the Kyrocera printers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will. I discovered this myself after uninstalling KB5000802, I paused updates for about 14 days. 14 days later, Win 10 reinstalled the update.